# Generate a segmented curved path in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, path

I was wondering how to generate a segmented `path` following a curved line using d3.js.
I am looking for suggestions on how to generate an output **where each segment has different `paths` with their own `fill` and `stroke`**. Here's an example of what I am looking for created without using d3.js.

[image]

I have considered `d3.line` as an option to generate the x, and y coordinates of the path and `d3.arc` to draw the different segments. Unfortunately, I don't see a way where `d3.arc` would work out of a circle. I am not sure what's the best way to proceed so I was hoping to get some feedback on how to solve this. I will include some code with my attempts once I receive some guidance.

Comment: Calculating the segment's outline is pretty complicated. You might consider to draw your segments via cloned `<path>` elements with different stroke-widths and `stroke-dasharray` values to emulate separate fill areas. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWPQWMb)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments you could use a stroke-dasharray. Here I use a `<use>` element to repeat a short dash and then use stoke-dashoffset to position the dash along the path.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 35 32" width="400">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M 31 32 C 31 10 5 36 5 17 C 5 1 32 18 25 2"
    stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2.6 100"
    pathLength="60" />
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver"/>
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-3" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-6" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-9" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="gray" stroke-dashoffset="-12" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="yellow" stroke-dashoffset="-15" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="navy" stroke-dashoffset="-18" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-21" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-24" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-27" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-30" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-33" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-36" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-39" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-42" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="gray" stroke-dashoffset="-45" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="yellow" stroke-dashoffset="-48" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="navy" stroke-dashoffset="-51" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-54" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-57" />
</svg>
```

Unfortunately it does not have a stroke (well, it is a stroke, but in this context I guess we could call it a fill). A solution could be to have a second path that creates the "feel" of "strokes" around each tile.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 35 32" width="400">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M 31 32 C 31 10 5 36 5 17 C 5 1 32 18 25 2"
    stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 .4 2.6 100"
    pathLength="60.4" />
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver"/>
  <path d="M 31 32 C 31 10 5 36 5 17 C 5 1 32 18 25 2"
    stroke-width="5.8" stroke="black" fill="none" pathLength="60" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-3" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-6" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-9" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="gray" stroke-dashoffset="-12" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="yellow" stroke-dashoffset="-15" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="navy" stroke-dashoffset="-18" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-21" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-24" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-27" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-30" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-33" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-36" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="orange" stroke-dashoffset="-39" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-42" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="gray" stroke-dashoffset="-45" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="yellow" stroke-dashoffset="-48" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="navy" stroke-dashoffset="-51" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="-54" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="green" stroke-dashoffset="-57" />
</svg>
```

If each tile doesn't need it's own color the path could be made as a mask on another path. Almost like a gauge/meter. If you are interested I could make an example of that as well.

Comment: Thanks @chrwahl. Your solution gets there halfway! It also helps me understand other potential solutions. Unfortunately, for this particular case I want full control of the `fill` and `stroke` of each segment of the curved path. That's why recently I have been trying to solve this drawing two parallel curves, dividing those curves in equal segments and now I am trying to connect those line segments to create the segments I am looking for via `path`. I'll share the code if I succeed on this.